# JIRA REST API with jQuery using ap.require()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I Create the one php file and call the jira Rest api using AP.require()

below error is come

1)

> all.js:82 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideFooter' of
>   undefined

2)

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined

```
   AP.require('request', function(request) {
     request({
        url: "https://star123.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
        "fields": {
           "project": {
              "key": "TEST"
           },
           "summary": "I just created a new issue!",
           "issuetype": {
              "name": "Task"
           }
        }
        },
        success: function (response) {
          console.log("success")              
        },
        error: function (response) {
           console.log("error")
        }
     });        
  });
```